# I am not getting response REST API (POST) Content Type FormUrlEncode

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

When I try in postman it working fine and I am getting a response.

[image]

I am trying to make a request. and I am not getting any response please look into my code and let me know where I did wrong?

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "11223asda"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "1232asdasa"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "authcode3"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "http://www.google.com/")

                });

                var uri = new Uri("https://sandbox-api.userdomain.com/v2/oauth2/token");


                // var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(obj);

                //HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

                request.Content = content;

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: code provided looks correct. You will need to provide more details. How is that method that wraps that code called? provide a [mcve] that can help us better understand your actual problem.

Comment: Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `response.StatusCode`? Looks like `Debug.WriteLine` is not writing to the debug window.

Comment: After HttpResponseMessage it's not coming into the line "response.statuscode" @ChetanRanpariya I am not getting any response while sending a request it automatically started to "GC".

Comment: The API might be taking time to respond. Did you put a breakpoint on `Debug.WriteLine(` line and wait for it to be hit? Does your code break with any exception ? Also try having breakpoint in Catch block if you have any.

Comment: Your working postman example and your code example use different URLs...dexcom vs userdomain

Comment: yeah, I changed the URL in my code then also i am not getting any response.@Mark

Comment: As you said I tried not working @ChetanRanpariya I set  as                    "client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);"

Comment: @Bharath try `client.PostAsync(uri, content)` instead of  `client.SendAsync(request)`

Answer (score 1):

For this type of work I use this lib :
https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient

```
var client = new TinyRestClient(new HttpClient(),"https://sandbox-api.userdomain.com/");

var response = await client.
                PostRequest("v2/oauth2/token").
                AddFormParameter("client_id", "France").
                AddFormParameter("client_secret", "Paris").
                AddFormParameter("grant_type", "Paris").
                AddFormParameter("redirect_uri", "Paris").
                ExecuteAsync<Response>();
```

Hope that helps!